# How to force quit an application when Task Manager itself doesn't respond?

Tags: windows, windows-8

We've all had that moment where we needed to `CTRL-ALT-DELETE` and open Task Manager to forcefully end a program that's not responding. But what do I do when Task Manager itself doesn't respond?

[image: Task manager not responding.]

Comment: To be clear, this is a fresh install of Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get to a command prompt, use the [TASKKILL](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/kill-processes-from-the-command-prompt-in-windows-7/) command.

Answer (score 0):

Open a Powershell prompt (you may have to right click and run as Admin depending on the app)

Type `ps` and hit enter

Find the name of the offending program

Then type `Stop-Process -processname notepad` replace notepad with the process name